# Populate listview with 2 strings from webservices in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have wrote the code to populate **List View** with single string. But, I don't know how to populate with 2 strings.. Somebody, please help me out.

**here is my code:**

```
public class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<FlowerAdapter.Flowers> flowersList = new ArrayList<FlowerAdapter.Flowers>();
    String url = "http://113.193.30.155/MobileService/MobileService.asmx/GetSampleData";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String content = FlowerAdapter.HttpULRConnect.getData(url);

        return content;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){


        try {

            JSONArray ar =new JSONArray(s);

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=ar.getJSONObject(i);
```

here i want to get 2 strings **"NAME"**&**"PERCENTAGE"**....but i dont know how to get the another string and bind it in **List View**.

```
                FlowerAdapter.Flowers flowers= new FlowerAdapter.Flowers();
                flowers.setName(jsonObject.getString("NAME"));
                flowersList.add(flowers);


                FlowerAdapter adapter=new FlowerAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.flower_list_xml,flowersList);
                listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: flowers.setPercentage(jsonObject.getString("PERCENTAGE"));

Answer (score 1):

first, add all the field in your `Flowers` class with setters and getters
Then set it in the object which you are passing to adapter.

Comment: could you please explain it as a code snippet...it ll be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

i have created  a setter for this second string and called it...thats all..

flowers.setPercentage(jsonObject.getString("Percentage");